# count element in array?

Tags: php

I have an Array like this (when I `print_r`).  How can I sum all elements in this Array?
In this example, the sum is 0+1=1

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0 )
        [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) )
```

Comment: Only elm `[1][0]` has the value `1` so I'm not quite sure _how_ this value (2) should be calculated?! Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the 'array_reduce' function: array_reduce: http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Taken from the documentation:

```
function rsum($v, $w)
{
    $v += $w;
    return $v;
}
$sum = array_reduce($a, "rsum");
```